# How to fix java.lang.string cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.readableArray?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-bridge, react-native-native-ui-component

I was creating a native Image component in the Android and here is some code that I used.

ViewManager.java

```
// setting the source of the ImageView

@ReactProp(name = "src")
public void setSrc(ReactImageView view, @Nullable ReadableArray sources) {
    view.setSource(sources);
}
```

App.tsx

```
 <POCImageView src={'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image#/media/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png'}
```

error I'm getting is
**`java.lang.string cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.readableArray`**

how can I fix this ? what am I doing wrong? how to pass the src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking deeper into the props and it's type, I was able to fix this using below code.

```
<POCImageView
   style={{height: 500, width: 300}}
   resizeMode={'cover'}
   src={[
          {
            uri: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image#/media/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png',
          },
        ]}
/>
```